# unable to display ArcGIS dynamic map in Android

Tags: arcgis-android

I am unable to display ArcGIS dynamic map in Android but same code works for Tile maps.

Error I am getting is

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load GLMapCore
>   from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld-1,
>   /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the (correct) native libraries associated with your project.  If you are in Eclipse, right click your project and select one of the following depending on which one is not grayed out:

**ArcGIS Tools > Convert to ArcGIS Android Project**

This option converts an android project to an arcgis android project.  Most likely not your issue as you state your code is working with Tile maps.

**or**

**ArcGIS Tools > Fix Project Properties**

This option updates a project with versioned libs in Eclipse, e.g. update the native libs to a newer version.